# Can pd.cut use interval range and labels together?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fiddling around with something like this.

```
bins = [0, .25, .5, .75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
labels = ['0', '.25', '.5', '.75', '1', '1.25', '1.5', '1.75', '2']
dataset['RatingScore'] = pd.cut(dataset['Rating'], bins, labels)
```

What I am actually getting is a range, like this: `(0.75, 1.0]`

I would like to get results like this: `.75 or 1 or 1.25`

Is it possible to get a specific number and NOT a range?  Thanks.

Andy, your code runs, and it gives me actual numbers, rather than ranges, but I'm seeing a lot of gaps too.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `labels` to the 3rd parameter of `pd.cut`. The third parameter of `pd.cut` is `right=...`. It accepts `True/False` as values. `labels` is non-empty list, so it is considered as `True`. Therefore, `pd.cut` executes as there is no label. You need to use keyword parameter to correctly specify list `labels` as labels for `pd.cut`.
Another thing, number of `bins` must be one item more than `labels`. You need to add `np.inf` to the right of list `bins`

```
s = pd.Series([0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 2])
bins = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, np.inf]
labels = ['0', '.25', '.5', '.75', '1', '1.25', '1.5', '1.75', '2']

s_cat = pd.cut(s, bins=bins, labels=labels)

Out[1165]:
0       0
1      .5
2       0
3     .75
4    1.75
dtype: category
Categories (9, object): [0 < .25 < .5 < .75 ... 1.25 < 1.5 < 1.75 < 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Andy!  I'll go with your recommendation, just because it's a bit easier to setup and maintain.  Both solutions worked, but I have a lot of gaps.  How can I fill in all the spaces?

Comment: could you explain more on gaps? could you edit question to show how those gaps look like?

Comment: I just added an image.

Comment: I just realized these are NANs.  They print in the console window but they don't show up when I export the dataframe to a CSV file.  Why would I get NANs?  Is it because there is no specific bin for some of these?

Comment: the image lacks the context, so I guess the gaps are in column `SpreadDeci`. I guess these gaps/NaN relates to how your dataframe index looks like and the assigment of the result of the `pd.cut` back to the dataframe. I can't answer due to lacking detail and context.  Could you post a new question with detail sample of your dataframe and the context of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add infinity to the bins you'll have as possible output float (`np.nan`) or interval let says you want to take the right interval you could try as follow

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fun(x):
    if isinstance(x, float) is True:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x.right

df = pd.DataFrame({"Rating":[.1* i for i in range(10)]})
bins = [0, .25, .5, .75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
df["RatingScore"] = pd.cut(df['Rating'], bins)

df["RatingScore"].apply(fun)

0     NaN
1    0.25
2    0.25
3    0.50
4    0.50
5    0.50
6    0.75
7    0.75
8    1.00
9    1.00
```